# DbGeography is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index or statistics

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, .net-4.6

I am on Entity Framework 6.1 code first and I'm trying to create an index on a column of type `DbGeography` as my app is primarily location-focused so *not indexing* is not an option.

Here is the relevant part on my class:

```
public class Post
{
  ...
    [Required, Index(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Required, Index(Order = 2)]
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

However when I run my app (I'm using SQL Azure) I get:

`Column 'Location' in table 'dbo.Posts' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index or statistics.`

How can I get rid of this problem without turning off spatial indexing?

Comment: Remove the index attribute an manually index the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spatial Types cannot be used as entity keys in Entity Framework since they work like Filtered Indexes. This post contains more information about using [Spatial Types in the Entity Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/04/spatial-types-in-the-entity-framework.aspx).